# Logical SELECT-OPTIONS in classes

Tags: class, if-statement, conditional-statements, selection, abap

I faced a problem with building complex logical conditions in class method through `SELECT-OPTIONS` statement:

```
IF col IN seltab.
  ...logic....
ENDIF.
```

I receive error **local SELECT-OPTIONS are not allowed...**

I coded according to the [example](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abenlog_exp_in_abexa.htm) in ABAPDOCU. The below piece of code also had no sense:

```
DATA: codes TYPE RANGE OF tcode.
codes-sign = 'I'.
codes-option = 'EQ'.
codes-low = 'VL32N'.
apppend codes.
```

I got the error **Codes is a table without header line and therefore has no component called sign**.

Is it possible to use logical selection tables in classes? If no what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and the system states exactly what was wrong. You need to declare this:

```
DATA: lt_range_codes TYPE RANGE OF tcode,         " this is an internal table WITHOUT a header line
      ls_range_codes LIKE LINE OF lt_range_codes. " this is a corresponding structure

ls_range_codes-sign   = 'I'.
ls_range_codes-option = 'EQ'.
ls_range_codes-low    = 'VL32N'.
APPEND ls_range_codes TO lt_range_codes.
```

Remember that tables with header lines are not allowed within ABAP Objects classes, so you always need an additional structure. Of course, a field symbol and `APPEND INITIAL LINE TO ... ASSIGNING <...>` will do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you can also create range tables in transaction SE11. I would recommend this if you use the same range table in multiple classes. Create a table data type with SE11, then go up to EDIT->DEFINE AS RANGE TABLE TYPE and the rest is self explanatory. Enter the element type you want a range table for and then you can use this type in all your classes.